# Should I version my API even if it isn't public?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, mobile, versioning

I am about to start implementing an API in my Rails application that will respond to the requests it receives from my mobile application. Whenever I check resources about creating an API with Rails, everyone seems to talk about versioning from the get go. I was wondering what could be the drawbacks of not versioning from the get go, besides I might regret it if I ever decide to go public with the API?

Comment: Think about some time in the future when you update your app and you need a newer API but some users will have the old version of the app and some will have the new version.

Comment: What are the drawbacks of versioning from the get go, I'm curious...

Comment: Design so that is also easier for *internal* use and maintainability. Programmers are also their own, albeit non-paying, customers.

Comment: @BradWerth Besides some more work nothing I guess. It's actually not that I don't want to do it, I just wanted to get opinions an information.

Answer (score 0):

Versioning helps you deal with problems. If you have a product named Foo, you may start at 1. (`Foo 1`) That first version was perfect and you decide to make a change. Your next version will be `Foo 2`. You have found a bug in `Foo 2`, and you can't fix it. Therefore, you revert back to `Foo 1`.

If you didn't version your product, then how would you know which `Foo` is stable? You may look at modification times, but that's not good enough.

Also, what if you go public (as you mentioned), and you haven't versioned the product? Then you will have to adapt and get used to the idea of versioning.